# Representation of the diagonal of a group in terms of product of subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

> **Conjecture.** Consider the additive abelian group $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider its diagonal $\Delta$. Then, $$\Delta=\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n_\alpha} (G_i^\alpha\times H_i^\alpha)\right)$$ for some index set $I$ such that for each $α∈I$ there exists an $n_α∈\mathbb{N}$ and a set of subgroups $G_{i}^\alpha\times H_i^\alpha$ with $i\in \{1,\ldots,n_\alpha\}$.

I don't have any idea whether the result it true or not. So I was trying to investigate which conditions on the subgroups are necessary to warrant that if $$(x,y)\in \displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n_\alpha} (G_i^\alpha\times H_i^\alpha)\right)$$ for some index set $I$ such that for each $α∈I$ there exists an $n_α∈\mathbb{N}$ and a set of subgroups $G_{i}^\alpha\times H_i^\alpha$ with $i\in \{1,\ldots,n_\alpha\}$ then $x=y$. But so far I have made no progress.

**My Question**

How can I prove or disprove the conjecture?

Comment: Without further information, I can only suppose the assertion to be that this is true for all choices of $I$, $n_\alpha$, $G^\alpha_i$, $H^\alpha_i$, in which case here's a counterexample. Choose $I=\{1\}$, $n_1=1$, $G^1_1=H^1_1=\mathbb R$, and then the right hand side of your equation is $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \ne \Delta$.

Comment: Or, to put it a different way, the symbols $I$ and $n_\alpha$ in your question have not been defined.

Comment: Edited. Is it ok now?

Comment: No, most of the notation is still not specified. What is $I$? What are the $n_{\alpha}$? What are these subgroups?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: $I$ is just some index set. $n_\alpha\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: So you think this will hold for any index set, any set of natural numbers and any set of subgroups?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: The conjecture is that there will exist **some** index set $I$ and for each $\alpha\in I$ an $n_\alpha\in \mathbb{N}$ and some set of subgoups $G_1^\alpha \times H_1^\alpha,\ldots, G_{n_\alpha}^\alpha \times H_{n_\alpha}^\alpha$ such that $\Delta$ has the said representation.

Comment: Then make the question precise by including all the relevant quantifiers.

Comment: Edited (again). Please let me know whether it is ok now.